# Keras predict causes CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use keras pre-trained InceptionResNetV2 to extract image features.
But it always causes CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY when I predict images, even though I only predict a single file.

The environment is CUDA 10.0, cudnn 7.4, tensorflow 1.13, RTX 2070. GPU memory is 8GB.

Here are codes:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
...
IR2 = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
...
features = IR2.predict_on_batch(np.array([test_image])) 
#test_image only contains one image
```

Error messages are:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:806] failed to allocate 3.53G (3794432768 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:211] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.39GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:211] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.39GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

Comment: How big is the input image that you are testing?

Comment: The shape is [299,299,3]. I have no idea what makes the memory exhausted. Can cudnn, CUDA and tensorflow compatibility cause this?